# How to select a second div with the same class

Tags: jquery

How to select a second div with the same class
Is there a selector that can select the same class div

How to select the second div of the same class after clicking $(this), and hide the border of B after clicking A

ty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.d1').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.d1').children('span').toggleClass('BdivC1-Span');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .d1 {
      display: block;
      color: lightgrey;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 15px;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    
    span {
      border-top: 2px solid red;
    }
    
    .BdivC1-Span {
      border: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="siblings">

  <div>div (父)
    <div class="d1"><span>1</span></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="d1"><span>2</span></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="d1"><span>3</span></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="d1"><span>4</span></div>
    <div></div>
    <p>p</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *hide the border of B after clicking A* - which one's B and which one's A?  You have 1,2,3,4 not A,B,C,D.

Comment: By "a second div", do you mean "the next div with the same class"?   eg click on `1` and `2` gets toggled?   `$(this).nextAll(".d1").first().toggleClass...`

Comment: I want the border of the d1 div below to close the border when the d1 div above is clicked

Comment: click "1" close "2" ->border   or  click "2" close "3"->border  ....

Comment: By "a second div", do you mean "the next div with the same class"  yes.

Comment: thanks you. can be used.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.next()` method. Its all explained here:
https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: `.next()` gets the *next* element - in OPs case that would be `<div></div>` so of no use.